# Syntax Error With Lists and Dictionaries

Tags: python, syntax

everyone! I have a Monopoly Simulator that is running into an error. I think that it is a syntax error, however, I cannot figure out the right syntax. Here is my code:

```
from random import randint

P1_Money=1640
#Sets inital money of player 1

P1_Position=0
#Sets initial position of both players

Jail_Number=0
#Sets Jail_Number which decides if the player can move out of jail

Board = ['Go', 'Mediterranean Avenue', 'Community Chest 1', 'Baltic Avenue', 'Income Tax', 'Reading Railroad', 'Oriental Avenue', 'Chance 1', 'Vermont Avenue', 'Connecticut Avenue', 'Jail', 'St. Charles Place', 'Electric Company', 'States Avenue', 'Virginia Avenue', 'Pennsylvania Railroad', 'St. James Place', 'Community Chest 2', 'Tenessee Avenue', 'New York Avenue', 'Free Parking', 'Kentucky Avenue', 'Chance 2', 'Indiana Avenue', 'Illinois Avenue', 'B. & O. Railroad', 'Atlantic Avenue', 'Ventnor Avenue', 'Water Works', 'Marvin Gardens', 'Go To Jail', 'Pacific Avenue', 'North Carolina Avenue', 'Community Chest 3', 'Pennsylvania Avenue', 'Short Line', 'Chance 3', 'Park Place', 'Luxury Tax', 'Boardwalk']
#List of all of the squares on the board

BoardLands = {'Go':[0,-200], 'Mediterranean Avenue': [0,2], 'Community Chest 1':0, 'Baltic Avenue':[0,4], 'Income Tax':[0,200], 'Reading Railroad':[0,200], 'Oriental Avenue':[0,6], 'Chance 1':[0,0], 'Vermont Avenue':[0,6], 'Connecticut Avenue':[0,8], 'Jail':[0,0], 'St. Charles Place':[0,0], 'Electric Company':[0,0], 'States Avenue':[0,10], 'Virginia Avenue':[0,12], 'Pennsylvania Railroad':[0,200], 'St. James Place':[0,14], 'Community Chest 2':[0,0], 'Tenessee Avenue':[0,14], 'New York Avenue':[0,16], 'Free Parking':[0,0], 'Kentucky Avenue':[0,18], 'Chance 2':[0,0], 'Indiana Avenue':[0,18], 'Illinois Avenue':[0,20], 'B. & O. Railroad':[0,200], 'Atlantic Avenue':[0,22], 'Ventnor Avenue':[0,22], 'Water Works':[0,0], 'Marvin Gardens':[0,22], 'Go To Jail':[0,0], 'Pacific Avenue':[0,26], 'North Carolina Avenue':[0,26], 'Community Chest 3':[0,0], 'Pennsylvania Avenue':[0,28], 'Short Line':[0,200], 'Chance 3':[0,0], 'Park Place':[0,35], 'Luxury Tax':[0,200], 'Boardwalk':[0,50]}
print (BoardLands['Chance 1'][1])
#Example of value in dictionary: 'Made Up Name': [0,20]
#'Made up name' is the name of the square, the first value in the list is the number of lands it has recieved, and the second value in the list is how much money you recieve from landing on it, with the exception of Community Chests and Chance Squares, which are handled by their respective handlers.

#print (Board[2], Board[17], Board[33]) All of the Community Chests
#print (Board[7], Board[22], Board[36]) All of the Chances
i=0 #Sets initial value for Itteration

while (i<500):
  if Jail_Number==0:
    P1_Position = (P1_Position+randint(1,6)+randint(1,6))
    if P1_Position>39:
      P1_Position=P1_Position-40

  else:
    Die_1=randint(1,6)
    Die_2=randint(1,6)
    if Die_1==Die_2:
      P1_Position = (P1_Position+Die_1+Die_2)
      Jail_Number=0
      print ('Player moved out of jail!')
    else:
      Jail_Number=Jail_Number-1

  print('Board Location of Player One: ', Board[P1_Position])      
  #Displays what player landed on what square
  if P1_Position == 2 or P1_Position == 17 or P1_Position == 33:   
      Random_Integer = randint(1,17)
      if Random_Integer == 1:
        BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]] = BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]]+1   
        P1_Position = 0
        print('Community Chest Reads: Advance to Go')
        print('Player Moved to Go!')
      elif Random_Integer == 2:
        print('Bank error in your favor - collect $75')
      elif Random_Integer == 3:
        print('Doctor\'s fees - Pay $50')
      elif Random_Integer == 4:
        print('Get out of jail free! - This card may be kept until needed, or sold')
      elif Random_Integer == 5:
        BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]] = BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]]+1
        P1_Position = 10
        Jail_Number = 3
        print('Go to jail - go directly to jail - Do not pass Go, do not collect $200')
        print('Player Moved to Jail!')
      elif Random_Integer == 6:
        print('It\'s your birthday! Collect $10 from each player')
      elif Random_Integer == 7:
        print('Grand Opera Night - collect $50 from every player for opening night seats')
      elif Random_Integer == 8:
        print('Income Tax Refund - Collect $200')
      elif Random_Integer == 9:
        print('Life Insurance Matures - Collect $100')
      elif Random_Integer == 10:
        print('Pay Hospital Fees of $100')
      else:
        print('I\'m lazy')
    #Community Chest Handler
  if P1_Position == 30:
    P1_Position = 10
    Jail_Number = 3
    BoardLands[Board[30],[(1)]] = BoardLands[Board[30],[(1)]]+1
    print("Player moved to jail")
  if P1_Position == 12 or P1_Position == 27:   #Utilities Handler
    P1_Money=P1_Money-((randint(1,6)+randint(1,6))*4)
  BoardLands[(Board[P1_Position]),[1]] = BoardLands[(Board[P1_Position]),[1]]+1
  #Updates statistics collector on what square was landed on
  i=i+1
  #Updates Itteration

print(" ")
print(" ")
print("Board Lands Stats")
for square in BoardLands:
  print (" ")
  print (square,  ":", BoardLands[square])
```

When ever I try to run the program, the error:
"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 81, in 
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'" always pops up. 
Thanks, everyone!

Comment: `BoardLands[Board[30],[(1)]]` is strange syntax. Do you mean `BoardLands[Board[30]][1]`?

Comment: Yes, thank you! However, when I do that, another error pops up: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 81, in <module>
TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Comment: You have `{...'Community Chest 1':0...}` in your dictionary - you should make the value of this key a list like all of the other entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you're doing and have tested a working version of your code.

First, @asongtoruin is correct, the syntax you use when referencing `BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]]` was causing errors for two reasons.

1. **Syntax for list indexing within a dictionary value**

`BoardLands[(Board[P1_Position]), [1]] = BoardLands[(Board[P1_Position]), [1]] + 1`

I could see you were trying to update the square's hit count when running this code. I won't go into details but this way is just wrong for many reasons. The correct way to access that list item is `BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]][0]` and a better way to simply add `+ 1` to the list item is `BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]][0] += 1`

2. **Object Types**

Your `BoardLands` dictionary contains key-value pairs where the value can be either a:

- `list()` | `'Mediterranean Avenue': [0, 2]`
- `int()` | `'Community Chest 1': 0`

You need to account for both cases throughout your code. I've added if statements to check the object type before moving on.

```
if isinstance(BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]], type(list())):
    BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]][0] += 1
elif isinstance(BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]], type(int())):
    BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]] += 1
```

Here's the code I got to work after tweaking these few things.

```
from random import randint

P1_Money = 1640
# Sets inital money of player 1

P1_Position = 0
# Sets initial position of both players

Jail_Number = 0
# Sets Jail_Number which decides if the player can move out of jail

Board = ['Go', 'Mediterranean Avenue', 'Community Chest 1', 'Baltic Avenue', 'Income Tax', 'Reading Railroad',
         'Oriental Avenue', 'Chance 1', 'Vermont Avenue', 'Connecticut Avenue', 'Jail', 'St. Charles Place',
         'Electric Company', 'States Avenue', 'Virginia Avenue', 'Pennsylvania Railroad', 'St. James Place',
         'Community Chest 2', 'Tenessee Avenue', 'New York Avenue', 'Free Parking', 'Kentucky Avenue', 'Chance 2',
         'Indiana Avenue', 'Illinois Avenue', 'B. & O. Railroad', 'Atlantic Avenue', 'Ventnor Avenue', 'Water Works',
         'Marvin Gardens', 'Go To Jail', 'Pacific Avenue', 'North Carolina Avenue', 'Community Chest 3',
         'Pennsylvania Avenue', 'Short Line', 'Chance 3', 'Park Place', 'Luxury Tax', 'Boardwalk']
# List of all of the squares on the board

BoardLands = {'Go': [0, -200], 'Mediterranean Avenue': [0, 2], 'Community Chest 1': 0, 'Baltic Avenue': [0, 4],
              'Income Tax': [0, 200], 'Reading Railroad': [0, 200], 'Oriental Avenue': [0, 6], 'Chance 1': [0, 0],
              'Vermont Avenue': [0, 6], 'Connecticut Avenue': [0, 8], 'Jail': [0, 0], 'St. Charles Place': [0, 0],
              'Electric Company': [0, 0], 'States Avenue': [0, 10], 'Virginia Avenue': [0, 12],
              'Pennsylvania Railroad': [0, 200], 'St. James Place': [0, 14], 'Community Chest 2': [0, 0],
              'Tenessee Avenue': [0, 14], 'New York Avenue': [0, 16], 'Free Parking': [0, 0],
              'Kentucky Avenue': [0, 18], 'Chance 2': [0, 0], 'Indiana Avenue': [0, 18], 'Illinois Avenue': [0, 20],
              'B. & O. Railroad': [0, 200], 'Atlantic Avenue': [0, 22], 'Ventnor Avenue': [0, 22],
              'Water Works': [0, 0], 'Marvin Gardens': [0, 22], 'Go To Jail': [0, 0], 'Pacific Avenue': [0, 26],
              'North Carolina Avenue': [0, 26], 'Community Chest 3': [0, 0], 'Pennsylvania Avenue': [0, 28],
              'Short Line': [0, 200], 'Chance 3': [0, 0], 'Park Place': [0, 35], 'Luxury Tax': [0, 200],
              'Boardwalk': [0, 50]}
print(BoardLands['Chance 1'][1])
# Example of value in dictionary: 'Made Up Name': [0,20]
# 'Made up name' is the name of the square, the first value in the list is the number of lands it has recieved, and the second value in the list is how much money you recieve from landing on it, with the exception of Community Chests and Chance Squares, which are handled by their respective handlers.

# print (Board[2], Board[17], Board[33]) All of the Community Chests
# print (Board[7], Board[22], Board[36]) All of the Chances
i = 0  # Sets initial value for Itteration

while (i < 500):
    if Jail_Number == 0:
        P1_Position = (P1_Position + randint(1, 6) + randint(1, 6))
        if P1_Position > 39:
            P1_Position = P1_Position - 40

    else:
        Die_1 = randint(1, 6)
        Die_2 = randint(1, 6)
        if Die_1 == Die_2:
            P1_Position = (P1_Position + Die_1 + Die_2)
            Jail_Number = 0
            print('Player moved out of jail!')
        else:
            Jail_Number = Jail_Number - 1

    print('Board Location of Player One: ', Board[P1_Position])
    # Displays what player landed on what square
    if P1_Position == 2 or P1_Position == 17 or P1_Position == 33:
        Random_Integer = randint(1, 17)
        if Random_Integer == 1:
            if isinstance(BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]], type(list())):
                BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]][0] += 1
            elif isinstance(BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]], type(int())):
                BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]] += 1
            P1_Position = 0
            print('Community Chest Reads: Advance to Go')
            print('Player Moved to Go!')
        elif Random_Integer == 2:
            print('Bank error in your favor - collect $75')
        elif Random_Integer == 3:
            print('Doctor\'s fees - Pay $50')
        elif Random_Integer == 4:
            print('Get out of jail free! - This card may be kept until needed, or sold')
        elif Random_Integer == 5:
            if isinstance(BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]], type(list())):
                BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]][0] += 1
            elif isinstance(BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]], type(int())):
                BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]] += 1
            P1_Position = 10
            Jail_Number = 3
            print('Go to jail - go directly to jail - Do not pass Go, do not collect $200')
            print('Player Moved to Jail!')
        elif Random_Integer == 6:
            print('It\'s your birthday! Collect $10 from each player')
        elif Random_Integer == 7:
            print('Grand Opera Night - collect $50 from every player for opening night seats')
        elif Random_Integer == 8:
            print('Income Tax Refund - Collect $200')
        elif Random_Integer == 9:
            print('Life Insurance Matures - Collect $100')
        elif Random_Integer == 10:
            print('Pay Hospital Fees of $100')
        else:
            print('I\'m lazy')
            # Community Chest Handler
    if P1_Position == 30:
        P1_Position = 10
        Jail_Number = 3
        BoardLands[Board[30]][0] += 1
        print("Player moved to jail")
    if P1_Position == 12 or P1_Position == 27:  # Utilities Handler
        P1_Money = P1_Money - ((randint(1, 6) + randint(1, 6)) * 4)

    if isinstance(BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]], type(list())):
        BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]][0] += 1
    elif isinstance(BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]], type(int())):
        BoardLands[Board[P1_Position]] += 1
    # Updates statistics collector on what square was landed on
    i = i + 1
    # Updates Itteration

print(" ")
print(" ")
print("Board Lands Stats")
for square in BoardLands:
    print(" ")
    print(square, ":", BoardLands[square])
```